# one linux connect to another ip,How to use docker make them into images and deploy to somewhere else

Tags: linux, docker

Now I have two Linux PC,mongodb is in the first PC which IP is `192.168.1.33`,and a 
java application on another Linux connect to the mongodb on 192.168.1.33

What I want to do is,prepare everything and make both Linux systems into docker images,and when I am in productive environment,I can simply restore the images that I prepared,and everything is OK,so I do not need complex deployment steps.

but the problem is,the IP of mongodb will change,and the IP `192.168.1.33` is written  in my configuration file of my java application,it will not change automatically,is there a automated way?

Comment: Are you absolute beginner to Docker and container technology? Based on your answer I would like to frame my answer to this question.

Comment: @Akshaybarahate yes,I am begginer,know only a little simple work

Comment: You should have a look at docker-compose. [Refer here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Basics***

- We create Docker-file with minimal installation steps.
- We create docker-Image from that Docker-file in step-1.
- We create container from the step-2 image and expose the important port as required.

**For your problem.**

1. [creating-a-docker-image-with-mongodb](https://medium.com/@pablo_ezequiel/creating-a-docker-image-with-mongodb-4c8aa3f828f2) This article will help to dockerize the mongodb.

   > but the problem is,the IP of mongodb will change,and the IP
   >   192.168.1.33 is written in my configuration file of my java application,it 
   >   will not change automatically,is there a automated way?

   - If you expose the mongo-db port to docker host you can use same
     `docker-host-IP:<exposed-port>`
   - **Ref from the article** `sudo docker run -p 27017:27017 -i -t my_new_mongodb`
   - **Example:** `192.168.1.33` is your docker-host where mongodb container is running with exposed port `27017`. You can add `192.168.1.33:27017` to your JAVA app.

   > What I want to do is,prepare everything and make both Linux systems
   >   into docker images

   - You can not convert your VM to direct docker images. Instead you can follow the steps written in **Basics** and dockerize the both DB and application layer.

2.[dockerize-your-java-application](https://medium.com/faun/dockerize-your-java-application-ec7ac056d066) refer this link and dockerize you application based on requirements.

3. Step 1 & 2 will help you to build docker images which you can deploy to multiple servers.

Comment: @eascape please let me know if this help you.

Comment: `Example: 192.168.1.33 is your docker-host where .. mongo...running..` Here you mean 192.168.1.33 is a host name rather than a ip,right?

Comment: docker-host is where you install docker daemon and used that VM's resource (CPU,RAM,Storage) for container virtualization.Once you expose your port, You can access that container either way (docker-host host name or IP).

Comment: But in your case as it's two different containers and need to communicate with each other you have to explore the networking aspect of docker also. Both the container has to be connected to same docker network. Don't get confuse with network as of now. Explore the image creation and deployment and then jump to connection part.